# Trigger CPU cache write back manually in java: possible? necessary?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, cpu-cache, game-loop

I am writing a video game in my spare time and have a question about data consistency when introducing mult-threading.

At the moment my game is single threaded and has a simple game loop as it is taught in many tutorials:

```
while game window is not closed
{
    poll user input
    react to user input
    update game state
    render game objects
    flip buffers
}
```

I now want to add a new feature to my game where the player can automate certain tasks that are long and tedious, like walking long distances (fast travel). I may chose to simply "teleport" the player character to their destination but I would prefer not to. Instead, the game will be sped up and the player character will actually walk as if the player was doing it manually. The benefit of this is that the game world will interact with the player character as usual and any special events that might happen will still happen and immediately stop the fast travel.

To implement this feature I was thinking about something like this:

- Start a new thread (worker thread) and have that thread update the game state continuously until the player character reaches its destination
- Have the main thread no longer update the game state and render the games objects as usual and instead display the travel progress in a more simplistic manner
- Use a synchronized message queue to have the main thread and the worker thread communicate
- When the fast travel is finished or canceled (by player interaction or other reasons) have the worker thread die and resume the standard game loop with the main thread

In pseudo code it may look like this:

```
[main thread]
while game window is not closed
{
    poll user input

    if user wants to cancel fast travel
    {
        write to message queue player input "cancel"
    }

    poll message queue about fast travel status

    if fast travel finished or canceled
    {
        resume regular game loop
    } else {
        render travel status
        flip buffers
    }
}

[worker thread]
while (travel ongoing)
{
    poll message queue

    if user wants to cancel fast travel
    {
        write to message queue fast travel status "canceled"
        return
    }

    update game state

    if fast travel is interrupted by internal game event
    {
        write to message queue fast travel status "canceled"
        return
    }

    write to message queue fast travel status "ongoing"
}
if travel was finished
{
    write to message queue fast travel status "finished"
}
```

The message queue will be some kind of two-channeled synchronized data structure. Maybe two ArrayDeque's with a Lock for each. I am fairly certain this will not be too much trouble.

What I am more concerned is caching problems with the game data:

- 1.a) Could it be that the worker thread, after being started, may see old game data because the main thread may run on a different core which has cached some of its results?
- 1.b) If the above is true: Would I need to declare every single field in the game data as volatile to protect myself with absolute guarantee against inconsistent data?
- 2) Am I right to assume that performance would take a non trivial hit if all fields are volatile?
- 3) Since I only need to pass the data between threads at few and well controlled points in time, would it be possible to force all caches to write back to main memory *instead* of using volatile fields?
- 4) Is there a better approach? Is my concept perhaps ill conceived?

Thanks for any help and sorry for the big chunk of text. I thought it would be easier to answer the question if you know the intended use.

Comment: It's kind of broad, but you could probably achieve the same result using your existing game loop, simply by skipping the user input stage and taking the input from a "queue" of some kind. The problem is knowing when to inject certain input events based on the users current location, but I'm sure if you have a pre-defined path for the user to follow, you can keep track of where they are and what the next event will need to be in order to continue along that path - just as an idea

Comment: Yes but then the window would become unresponsive during the fast travel. I want the fast travel to go as fast as possible, that is as fast as the CPU cam do the computations. The game window will still be limited in its update speed by the graphics pipeline.

Comment: You don't have to care about cache consistency as long as you are using a [SMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing) system and not a large-scale [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access)/cluster system.

Comment: Is it 100% guaranteed that all people who ever want to play my game would always have an SMP even many years (a decade or two perhaps) in the future? And even if so I am still generally interested in answers to my questions even if my concerns are unnecessary.

Comment: You should read up on the [`java memory model`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+memory+model)

Comment: @Andreas I am sorry but that doesgive me an answer to my question. If there is something I am missing I would appreciate if you could give me a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Robert He's writing Java code. What behavior he can rely on has nothing to do with whether he has an SMP or a NUMA system. Java primitives provide precisely the same semantics and guarantees either way.

Comment: There is no C-volatile "produce code as written" in Java. A non volatile variable can sometimes refer to the most recent value as accessible by the CPU, sometimes to an old value the optimizer decided to put there. This cannot happen with a C volatile variable where you always get the value as visible by the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

> Since I only need to pass the data between threads at few and well controlled points in time, would it be possible to force all caches to write back to main memory instead of using volatile fields?

No. That's not how any of this works. Let me give you very short answers to explain why you are thinking about this the wrong way:

> 1.a) Could it be that the worker thread, after being started, may see old game data because the main thread may run on a different core which has cached some of its results?

Sure. Or it might for some other reason. Memory visibility is not guaranteed, so you can't rely on it unless you use something guaranteed to provide memory visilbity.

> 1.b) If the above is true: Would I need to declare every single field in the game data as volatile to protect myself with absolute guarantee against inconsistent data?

No. Any method of assuring memory visibility will work. You don't have to do it any particular way.

> 2) Am I right to assume that performance would take a non trivial hit if all fields are volatile?

Probably. This would probably be the worst possible way to do it.

> 3) Since I only need to pass the data between threads at few and well controlled points in time, would it be possible to force all caches to write back to main memory instead of using volatile fields?

No. Since there is no "write cache back to memory" operation that assures memory visibility. Your platform may not even have such caches and the issue might be something else entirely. You're writing Java code, you don't have to think about how your particular CPU works, what cores or caches it has, or anything like that. That's one of the big advantages of using a language with semantics that are guaranteed and don't talk about cores, caches, or anything like this.

> 4) Is there a better approach? Is my concept perhaps ill conceived?

Absolutely. You are writing Java code. Use the various Java synchronization classes and functions and rely on them to prove the semantics they're documented to provide. Don't even think about cores, caches, flushing to memory, or anything like that. Those are hardware details that, as a Java programmer, you don't even have to ever think about.

Any Java documentation you see that talks about cores, caches, or flushes to memory is not actually talking about real cores, caches, or flushes to memory. It's just giving you some ways to think about hypothetical hardware so you can wrap your brain around why memory visibility and total ordering don't always work perfectly just by themselves. Your real CPU or platform may have completely different issues that bear no resemblance to this hypothetical hardware. (And real-world CPUs and systems have cache coherency guaranteed by hardware and their visibility/ordering issues in fact *are* completely different!)